# How does a Nakagami Random Variable behave?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

A Nakagami random variable has the following pdf
$$f_{\Omega,m}= \frac{2m^m}{\Gamma(m)\Omega^m} x^{2m-1}e^{-\frac{m}{\Omega}x^2}$$

I have two questions regarding this random variable,

1- Is a sum of Nakagami random variables also a Nakagami random variable?
For example if I have $Z=aX+bY$ where $a,b$ are non-negative constants and $X,Y$ are Nakagami random variables, what would be the distribution of $Z$? Would it also be Nakagami? Is the mean of $Z$ equal to $a+b$?

2- Assume I have Z a Nakagami random variable, what would be the distribution of $|Z|$ and the distribution of $|Z|^2$?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is a Nakagami random variable with parameters $(m,\Omega)$ then $X\geqslant0$ almost surely and $mX^2=\Omega U_m$ where $U_m$ is a gamma random variable with parameter $m$.

This shows that the answer to every question in 1. is "No", that the first question in 2. is absurd and allows to find the answer to the second question in 2. since $E(U_m)=m$.

Comment: THanks for the answer, I understand what you mean. However my main concern was pdf the SUM of Nagakami random variables. I havent got this from your answer? or am I missing something out @Did

Comment: Yes the PDF of a linear combination of (independent?) Nakagami random variables is not in my answer. Did you try the usual approach for a sum of independent random variables with known densities? Where were you stopped?

Comment: Yes I took the convolution of the the independent pdfs but couldnt arrive to a closed form solution? Is my approach right though?

Comment: I don't think there is a nice pdf for the sum, I have found numerous research papers evolving around this topic, am I right? Thanks

Comment: Yes, convolution is the way to go *if one assumes the summands are independent*.

Comment: Just for curiosity, why did you add the distribution of $|Z|$ again in the question?

Comment: To modify a question once it is answered is not advisable, because answers already posted are at risk of becoming offtopic. As it happened in the present case.

Comment: Oh ok got it thanks