# Function of Nakagami Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Does anyone know what the distribution of the sum of squared Nakagami is?
$$\sum_i^n X_i^2$$ $$X_i\sim \text{Complex Nakagami-m }$$

Is the distribution Erlang? Is the distribution the same as

$$\big|\sum_i X_i \big|^2 $$ or $$\big(\sum_i X_i \big)^2 $$ If the distribution of the above are not the same, do you know under what conditions they have the same distribution?

Cheers!

Comment: Did you try to use [the answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/975200) to your previous question at all?

Comment: @Did this is different, in this question I am trying to find the distribution of the sum of square Nag and not the square of the sum in my previous question which you tagged. Also in your last comment you mentioned that Nag is $\geq$ almost surely for which you said that my question my absurd given this fact, but my question was find the euclidean norm of Complex Nag and not the absolute

Comment: Nobody said this was the same question, I asked if you had **tried** to apply the other answer to this question.

Comment: I guess IF I am right about the sum of squared Nag being Erlang then the square of the sum ( my other question) is not the same !

Comment: @Did I guess you mean that, given the fact $X^2$ is Gamma distributed (your answer in previous question), then the sum of Gamma distributed is Erlang, then I am right. But do you think that the sum of squared complex Nagakami is the same?

Comment: @Did to bother you but is my analysis correct?